# Aluminium utensils.cleaning colours carbon stains

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, washer, carbon-monoxide

I saw  videos in youtube to clean Aluminium utensils with be boiled vinegar solution (boiled white vinegar+ detergent+salt+ lemon+ baking soda) or caustic soda solution or toilet cleaners harpic

I tried first the boiled vinegar solution (boiled white vinegar+ detergent+salt+ lemon+ baking soda) it worked great with brass and copper utensils they shine great and stell utensils or iron metal shined a lot and  the oil or carbon or stains removed in all metals but did not effected much with aluminium

Then I tried the castiic soda in hot water with toilet cleaner the  and left the utensils soaked overnight in the solution it reacted great with aluminium and all the black cas  deposits or all burnt black  ghee oil disolved in the solution but the aluminium part turned dark black.then silver colour I scrubbed but the black eas if aluminium is not changing much.

Is there any way any chemical to make shine Aluminium utensils it's new form kindly suggest opinions

Comment: It's really not a good idea to mix strong chemicals like caustic soda with commercial cleaning products. You might end up creating toxic cases. Also, mixing mild acids (vinegar, lemon) with mild bases (baking soda) only really creates bubble of CO2 and and maybe some salts left in the solution - neither of which are particularly good cleaners.

Comment: @behans how can remove toxics  of castic soda on aluminium utensils I think it's oxidated or aluminated the utensils the utensils turned silver to black and not being removed by scrubbing with sand paper scrubbers or vaccine...is there any profesional  cleaner for aluminium utensils or  any now solution to remove toxins or salts from.utrnsils I can remove and don't harm  health ...and how to turn black aluminated oxidated utensils reverse castic soda effect on utensils

Comment: @Androidquery  Utensils should not need more than elbow grease and detergent.  Think you might be at the point of replacing now.  There are aluminum cleaners sold  if you need heavy duty cleaning.

Comment: @crip659 bro thanx can u tell any havey duty aluminium cleaner which can do good job....can now  any aluminium cleaner or any chemical way to neutralize  unoxidise or reverse the toxic or  and get the shine silver colour back to

Comment: Never needed cleaners.  If it was dirty I sometimes use abrasive pads.  Think the chemicals you have used has ruin the aluminum.

Comment: OTOH, you now have really cool, hip _black_ utensils to use! I'll bet none of your friends have those.

Answer (score 2):

Acid ( vinegar = acetic acid) dissolves aluminum). Caustic ( sodium hydroxide ) dissolves aluminum. Neither one dissolves carbon/ black soot. A mix of vinegar and baking soda depends on the relative amounts. If I wanted to polish aluminum I would use wet/dry silicon carbide sand paper; 400 grit should be enough to remove carbon soot , then finer grades to polish. Use with detergent or soap. An electric buffer could be used to get a shine with automotive rubbing or polishing compound.

Comment: bro thanx  may be the aluminium dissolved  when I did the same I should ask before.... I did wrong....except sand paper any chemical do disolve carbon not metal aluminium utensils which are not toxic harmful....any  way to neutralize  oxidised or dsssolved aluminium toxication back...any solution to change black utensils back and get silver shine back...can u name any finer grades to polish....electric buffer to polish and reverse neutralise it back